# Setting object values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've tried my best to work this out, now I'm stuck, why does the fourth alert return undefined?

```
function buttonClick()
{
  var myTest = function()
  {
    var _setDirectlyInside = "So far so good...";
    var _setInFunctionCalledInside;
    var _setInFunctionCalledFromOutside;

    (function(){
      _setInFunctionCalledInside = "This would indicate scope isn't the problem?";
    })();

    return {
      basic : "Easy stuff",
      setDirectlyInside : _setDirectlyInside,
      setInFunctionCalledInside : _setInFunctionCalledInside,
      functionCallFromOutside : function(){
        _setInFunctionCalledFromOutside = "Why does this come back as undefined?";
      },
      setInFunctionCalledFromOutside : _setInFunctionCalledFromOutside
    }
  };

  var test = myTest();

  alert(test.basic); // Returns "Easy stuff"
  alert(test.setDirectlyInside); // Returns "So far so good..."
  alert(test.setInFunctionCalledInside); // Returns "This would indicate scope isn't the problem?"

  test.functionCallFromOutside();
  alert(test.setInFunctionCalledFromOutside); // Broken, returns undefined
}
```

Resolution:

```
setInFunctionCalledFromOutside : _setInFunctionCalledFromOutside, // Won't work
setInFunctionCalledFromOutsideGetter : function(){
    return _setInFunctionCalledFromOutside; // Will work
}

...

alert(test.setInFunctionCalledFromOutside); // Broken, returns undefined
alert(test.setInFunctionCalledFromOutsideGetter()); // Now works
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
return {
  basic : "Easy stuff",
  setDirectlyInside : _setDirectlyInside,
  setInFunctionCalledInside : _setInFunctionCalledInside,
  functionCallFromOutside : function(){
    _setInFunctionCalledFromOutside = "Why does this come back as undefined?";
  },
  setInFunctionCalledFromOutside : _setInFunctionCalledFromOutside
}
```

...will not cause `setInFunctionCalledFromOutside` to always return the same value of `_setInFunctionCalledFromOutside`. Rather, `_setInFunctionCalledFromOutside` will be evaluated at the time the `return` statement executes, and its value will be placed in `setInFunctionCalledFromOutside`. Thus, `functionCallFromOutside()` will have no effect on `setInFunctionCalledFromOutside`.

Comment: I thought functionCallFromOutside only contained the function definition, and it would be executed later by "test.functionCallFromOutside()"?  Where's my thinking wrong?

Comment: That's not where your thinking is wrong. It *is* executing when you call `test.functionCallFromOutside()`. The problem is your expectation that when the function sets `_setInFunctionCalledFromOutside = "Why does this come back as undefined?"` that it will *also* update the `setInFunctionCalledFromOutside` property.

Comment: Ahh I see where I went wrong, I wasn't expecting it to also update the value as such, but I was perceiving setInFunctionCalledFromOutside to act more like a C# getter property...  Changing it to a function, which I then call like a getter gives the desired outcome.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

[@nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) [said it best](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317966/361684), but he deleted his answer.  `setInFunctionCalledFromOutside` is ***not* a pointer** to `_setInFunctionCalledFromOutside`.  At the time the returned object was created, `setInFunctionCalledFromOutside` was assigned the value that `_setInFunctionCalledFromOutside` had.  Since, no value had yet been assigned, the value was `undefined`.  Changing the value of the one, doesn't change the value of the other.

A simpler example that illustrates the same principle:

```
var i = 0;
var n = i;
i++;
alert(i);  // 1
alert(n);  // still 0
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the others - for reference, JS passes strings and numbers by value.
It passes/assigns objects, arrays and functions by reference.

This isn't quite the snag that you're hitting (because your internal variable is `undefined` by the time you assign it to your external variable), but even if you did get the first part fixed:

```
var internal = "string";
return {
    external : internal,
    setInternal : function (val) { internal = val; }
};
```

That still doesn't fix the problem, as `obj.external` will always continue to be "string".
Why?
Because you set `external` to be the same value as `internal` at the time of assignment, and not to be equal to a `reference` of `internal` (ie: a pointer to it).

If you're looking for a pointer, then make `internal` an object:

```
var internal = { string : "my string" };
return {
    external : internal,
    setInternal : function (val) { internal.string = val; }
};

obj.external.string;  // "my string"
obj.setInternal("Bob was here");
obj.external.string;  // "bob was here"
```

Why does it now work?
Because internal is an object, and when you assign `external`'s value, you give it a pointer to the object which `internal` also has a pointer to.
When you change a property of `internal`, like `internal.string`, because `external` points to the same object, `external.string` has the same value.

If you set `internal` to something completely different, then you're pointing `internal` at something else (like `internal = null;`), therefore `external` will no longer change, when you modify `internal`, because `internal` is no longer pointing at the object which it used to be.